# Convert rows data into column in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

IN the below case i have 2 records but the no or records per id is not fixed...

```
SELECT InsuredMemberIdentifier,CoverageStartDate,CoverageEndDate FROM     
APCD.DBO.EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3 WHERE
InsuredMemberIdentifier=10190
```

Output is :

```
InsuredMemberIdentifier | CoverageStartDate |   CoverageEndDate
10190                      2014-01-01             2014-01-31
10190                      2014-02-01             2014-09-30
```

Required Output :

```
 10190 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-31 | 2014-02-01 | 2014-09-30
```

Comment: Do you need these dates to be in a single column or different? Could there be 3 or more rows with desired InsuredMemberIdentifier?

Comment: yes there can be three or more rows  and i need these dates in different column

Comment: Different number of columns is really not good idea, it's against concept of data representation in tables. You should change your requirments. PIVOT operator can only work with fixed number of columns (e.g. turn weekdays sunday, monday... to seven columns). WIth XML FOR you can concatenate all these values into a single column (nvarchar type) regardless of rows repetition (but only one column!)

Comment: so how can i get in single column all the values using xml for...

Comment: you can check my answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3 (InsuredMemberIdentifier INT, CoverageStartDate DATE,   CoverageEndDate DATE)

INSERT INTO #EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3
SELECT 10190 ,                     '2014-01-01',             '2014-01-31'
UNION ALL
SELECT 10190,                      '2014-02-01',             '2014-09-30'
```

**STEP 1**

1.Since you need to convert rows to columns(`Pivot`) based on two column values, you need to first converts values in two columns into a single column(which is called `Unpivot`).
2.Since you are new to `pivot`, I am creating a temporary table to hold values so that it will be easy for you to understand.
So the query will be as follows

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATES) COLUMNHEADERS,
InsuredMemberIdentifier,DATES
INTO #TEMP
FROM   #EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3
CROSS apply (VALUES (CoverageStartDate),
                   (CoverageEndDate)) cs (DATES)
WHERE InsuredMemberIdentifier = 10190
```

`CROSS APPLY` will work the same as

```
SELECT InsuredMemberIdentifier,CoverageStartDate
FROM #EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3
WHERE InsuredMemberIdentifier = 10190

UNION ALL

SELECT InsuredMemberIdentifier,CoverageEndDate
FROM #EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3
WHERE InsuredMemberIdentifier = 10190
```

so don't get confused.

**STEP 2**

The values in this variable will be the column names for the table that is to be generated as a part of `pivot`

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CAST(COLUMNHEADERS AS VARCHAR(50)) + ']', 
                '[' + CAST(COLUMNHEADERS AS VARCHAR(50)) + ']')
               FROM (SELECT COLUMNHEADERS FROM #TEMP) PV 
               ORDER BY COLUMNHEADERS
```

**STEP 3**

Since you cannot predict the number of date values or hardcode date values(since number of columns will be dynamic and cannot write by putting comma), you need to use `Dynamic Sql`.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = '--This is the query result - InsuredMemberIdentifier and columns with dates
             SELECT InsuredMemberIdentifier,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 -- Here you will select the columns before pivoting. COLUMNHEADERS will be name of column
                 -- and each date will be displayed under that column 
                 SELECT COLUMNHEADERS,InsuredMemberIdentifier,DATES
                 FROM #TEMP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 -- Tells what should be the values in each column(ie, values in 2014-01-01,2014-01-31 etc)
                 MIN(DATES)
                 -- You will tell SQL to show values in @cols to be the column names
                 -- by taking corresponding DATES from its corresponding COLUMNHEADERS
                 FOR [COLUMNHEADERS] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

When you give `PRINT @QUERY` instead of `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query`, it will show the below result

[image]

See, SQL Server generated column names `1,2,3,4` dynamically for you since you are using `Dynamic Sql`. When there is only two dates, only column names `1,2` will be generated.

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d023/3) to view result**

**FINAL RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to concatenate date values into a single column with `FOR XML` operator:

```
DECLARE @tb AS TABLE
(
    InsuredMemberIdentifier INT
    ,CoverageStartDate DATE
    ,CoverageEndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (10190, '2014-01-01', '2014-01-31');
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (10190, '2014-02-01', '2014-09-30');
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (10191, '2014-02-01', '2014-09-30');

SELECT DISTINCT InsuredMemberIdentifier
    ,ISNULL(STUFF(
        (SELECT ' ' + CAST(CoverageStartDate  AS NVARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + CAST(CoverageEndDate  AS NVARCHAR(15))
         FROM @tb tb_inner
         WHERE tb_inner.InsuredMemberIdentifier = tb.InsuredMemberIdentifier 
         FOR XML PATH (''))
         ,1,1,''), '') AS ConcatenatedDates
FROM @tb tb
WHERE InsuredMemberIdentifier = 10190
```

Comment: there dates are different

Comment: @Robin, got your idea, then TOP 1 will suit your requirments (edited answer)

Comment: i need both rows values but in a single row

Answer (score 0):

select a.InsuredMemberIdentifier,a.CoverageStartDate,a.CoverageEndDate,b.CoverageStartDate,b.CoverageEndDate from 
(select top 1 *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by InsuredMemberIdentifier order by (select 0)) as r from APCD.DBO.EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3 order by r )a ,
(select top 1 *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by InsuredMemberIdentifier order by (select 0)) as r from APCD.DBO.EdgeServer_EligibilityConsolidated_Part3 order by r desc) b

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at SQL pivot and unpivot

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx